# Returning data from database using Entity Framework to display in the browser through api controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement a project using ASP.Net MVC with Web Api. I could generate .edmx file and design diagram using Entity Framework Database first approach. I added API controller then tried to run the application like http://localhost:52078/api/City. It supposed to return me the table data as a result in xml or json format. but I am getting result as follows:

```
<ArrayOfcity xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/testAPI2.Models"/>
```

I am not able to receive the field values of City table. Kindly help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

For basic knowledge of web api you should click the url bellow..
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/659131/Understanding-and-Implementing-ASPNET-WebAPI

or send the propper code of your problem

Comment: I referred the link it was helpful. I tried the example, in that I couldn't get result for // GET api/values/5. this url shows me the same result of //GET api/values. How to retrieve the result for particular id?

Answer (score 0):

**Api Contoller:**

```
 [HttpGet]
            public RestaurantMenuCompleteModel GetRestaurantMenu(int RestaurantId)
            {
                return _restaurantRepository.GetRestaurantComleteMenu(RestaurantId);
            }
```

**WebApi.config-**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
          config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "ActionApi",
          routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
          );
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

**Url:**

http:/localhost:2031/api/restaurant/GetRestaurantMenu?RestaurantId=28